# Flutter/Android cannot find symbol startForeground()

Tags: java, android, flutter

I've been trying to get a background service working on Android.
But Android keeps telling me  that `startForeground()` cannot be found despite me handling the import correctly.

```
package com.example.helloservice;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.os.Build.VERSION;
import android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.app.Service;


import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.Result;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
  private static final String CHANNEL = "samples.flutter.io/battery";

  Intent i = new Intent(this, HelloService.class);
  Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

  Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this).setContentTitle("My Awesome")
      .setContentText("Doing some work").setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
    // createNotificationChannel();
    new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(new MethodCallHandler() {
      @Override
      public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, Result result) {
        if (call.method.equals("getBatteryLevel")) {
          int batteryLevel = getBatteryLevel();
          if (batteryLevel != -1) {
            result.success(batteryLevel);

            startService(i);
            startForeground(1337, notification);

..

  }
}
```

If it helps, I already have gradle compile version set to >27 and that my manifest have been setup with the service tag.

This is through platform code using Flutter, i tried starting a new project which did not fix the issue.

Comment: The `startForeground()` call goes in the `Service`, not in the `Activity`. The `startForegroundService()` method is what you want to use in the `Activity`, in place of `startService()`.

Comment: Thanks, im not sure how i missed that! I take it then the whole notification should be constructed in service as well?

Comment: Yeah, you could do that. I usually stick it in a static method in a utility class, so I can update the `Notification` from elsewhere, if need be. If you don't need to do that, then it's perfectly fine to do it all in the `Service`.